# deleting data from firebase console just like in mongoose

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I used `mongoose` database before. After the testing process and all we can delete the data from the mongoose website manually. Even the collection.

Now I am using firebase as my database and my question is that is there any functionality like removing authenticated user data manually from the database just like we do in `mongoose`. Or do we need to code to remove a particular user data from firebase?

I have a `firebase.js`

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "someKey",
    authDomain: "some domain",
    databaseURL: "someURL",
    projectId: "someID",
    storageBucket: "someBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "SomeId"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default firebaseApp;
```

and an `index.js` file:

```
import firebaseApp from './firebase';
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
    } else {
        console.log('user needs to be signed in');
    }
})
```

On submission I am seeing user in the web console

Is there any way to visualize the authenticated user in the firebase console, so that I  can delete it from the firebase web console?

in mongodb there will be a collection for the authentication purposes. That contain,say the username and password. Which is a collection of its own. And other collections based on other datas. What I am asking is that the user data authenticated by the above process, needs to be stored somewhere right in the firebase. Is there any way to get that user data and delete it?

Comment: you can delete manually from firebase console.

Comment: I'm confused! Your edit seems to have made this into 2 different questions. The first part of the question is about deleting data from Firebase Database through the console, which my answer relates to, but your code example is for Firebase Authentication. Please can you clarify what you are trying to achieve and what's not working?

Comment: what i was asking is that, in mongodb there will be a collection for the authentication purposes. That contain,say the username and password. Which is a collection of its own. And other collections based on other datas. Your answer clarifies deleting and manipulating data on the second case. What I am asking is that the user data authenticated by the above process, needs to be stored somewhere right in the firebase. Is there any way to get that user data and delete it?

Comment: I think I know you mean: I've updated my answer.

Comment: And now i got my required answer.Thanks a lot @Grimthorr for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) is your backend entry-point to your app's data, features and services.

The Database section of the console enables you to freely add & remove data in the Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore:

**Realtime Database**

[image: rtdb screenshot]

**Cloud Firestore**

[image: firestore screenshot]

There is a separate section for Authentication in the Firebase Console. When a user registers for your app, their profile data is passed to Firebase from the authentication provider (Google, Facebook, etc), but only the identifier (username, email, phone number), created date, signed in date and unique ID are displayed in the Firebase Console:

[image: authentication screenshot]

You can manually delete user accounts from the Firebase Console without having to write code to do so. Deleting an account will delete the associated authentication data and will stop the user from logging into your app.

To manually delete a user account:

1. Login to Firebase Console from a desktop browser
2. Select Authentication from the left menu
3. Hover over a user account in the list
4. Click the 3-dot icon on the right of the user row
5. Click "delete account" from the context menu

Comment: I added a data from my web app, but I can't see it in my firebase console though. Have any thoughts on that?

Comment: then your question is wrong. provide the code for writing to firebase. if its success then definitely it shows in console.

Comment: @KevinRED This is now 2 different questions. I think you may have fallen into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) trap. Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have edited the question now, can you look into it now?

Comment: This answer is really helpful and is possible when using a different data collection. What i want is the user data that firebase checks on my authentication. Is there any way to delete that saved authentication data?